# HttpClient Angular 9 converting nested json to nested object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to see if there's a more elegant way other than using map to accomplish the following:

I have a class with an array of another object. So my Meeting object has many users:

```
import { User } from './user';

export class Meeting {
  _id?: string;
  name: string;
  roomSid?: string;
  users: User[];
  contentList: any;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  createDate: Date;
}

export class User {
  _id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  dealerName: string;
  location: string;
  role: 'attendee' | 'host' | 'participant';
  videoServiceId: string;
  profilePic?: string;
  __v?: string;

  get isHost(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'host';
  }

  get isAttendee(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'attendee';
  }

  get isParticipant(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'participant';
  }

  get isClient(): boolean {
    return this.isAttendee || this.isParticipant;
  }
}
```

When I do:

```
this.httpClient
      .get<Meeting>(`${this.apiUrl}${meetingId}`)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError));
```

without using map to convert the received result from the get, the User object array is getting set incorrectly. My getters are undefined unless I do a Object.assign(new User, user). HttpGet returns the Meeting as a Meeting class just fine, just not the objects inside.

Is there something I'm missing or is this working as intended and I have no choice but to use map(). Although I feel that if I have another Object inside my User class, then things could get a bit messier.

For reference here is a response from the server:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "971c4160-c60c-11ea-8505-dff43e61059c",
            "firstName": "alex",
            "lastName": "oroszi",
            "dealerName": "here",
            "location": "here",
            "role": "attendee",
            "videoServiceId": "PA634a9331a9cad648bb6e6dbcea8e49a0"
        }
    ],
    "contentList": [],
    "_id": "5f0a005b627fb647f519118b",
    "name": "Room1",
    "startDate": "2020-07-11T16:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2020-07-11T17:00:00.000Z",
    "createDate": "2020-07-11T18:09:31.016Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying `` .get<Meeting>(`${this.apiUrl}${meetingId}`) `` you're letting TypeScript know that the get method will return a `Meeting` object which is not the case. If you check the result of your method with `data instanceof Meeting` it will return false. You will need to create a meeting object and populate it with the data received from the request.

The easiest way to do this without any libraries will probably be as follows.

```
export class Meeting {
  _id?: string;
  name: string;
  roomSid?: string;
  users: User[];
  contentList: any;

  constructor(data) {
    this._id = data._id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.roomSid = data.roomSid;
    this.users = data.users.map(user => new User(user));
    this.contentList = data.contentList;
    // ...
  }
}

export class User {
  _id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  dealerName: string;
  location: string;
  role: 'attendee' | 'host' | 'participant';
  videoServiceId: string;
  profilePic?: string;
  __v?: string;

  constructor(data) {
    this._id = data._id:
    this.firstName = data.firstName:
    // ...
  }

  get isHost(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'host';
  }

  get isAttendee(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'attendee';
  }

  get isParticipant(): boolean {
    return this.role === 'participant';
  }

  get isClient(): boolean {
    return this.isAttendee || this.isParticipant;
  }
}

function getMeeting(meetingId): Observable<Meeting> {
  this.httpClient.get<Meeting>(`${this.apiUrl}${meetingId}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      map(meeting => new Meeting(meeting)),
    );
}
```

The downside of this approach is the DRYness as the property name is repeated three times. An alternative is solutions such as [TypedJson](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON) which allow you to serialize and deserialze objects with help of decorators. Quick example of a model in TypedJSON:

```
@jsonObject
class Meeting {

    @jsonMember
    _id: string;
    
    @jsonArrayMember(User)
    users: Array<User>;
}
```

Comment: so even if I do something similar with Object.assing(new Meeting(), meeting) I do get an instance of the class now but still the same issue on the Users part. 

I'm assuming I have to write a constructor that will convert the Users? 

Or like you pointed out use a library

Comment: @AlexandruOroszi Indeed, `Object.assign(new Meeting(), meeting)` will **not** make `meeting.users` an array of actual `User` objects. The first code block in my answer has a constructor which maps the user array to an array of `User` objects. Both the constructor and library approach are valid.

Comment: That's what I thought. Perfect, thank you. I'll put this as the accepted answer. If you have any time and can name a few libraries to choose from to do these conversions just so I can browse I would greatly appreciate it. Cheers.

Comment: I recently did some comparing of these libraries and chose between these contenders: [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON), [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer), [cerialize](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize).